# useSelector causes multiple re-renders

Tags: react-native, redux, reducers

When using react-devtools it tells me that the reason my root component re-renderd was because hooks changed?

when I remove any useSelectors, my root component renders only once, when enabled it renders 6 times.

what are some guesses as to why this is happening?

```
import {
  /// Data State Constants...
  SET_USER_DATA,
  SET_BADGE_COUNT,
} from "../Actions/gameState";

const initialState = {
  /// Data state...
  userData: [],
  badgeCount: 0,
};

export default function gameState(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action || {};
  switch (type) {
    /////////////////////////
    /// Data state Reducers...
    /////////////////////////
    case SET_USER_DATA: {
      return { ...state, userData: payload };
    }
    case SET_BADGE_COUNT: {
      return { ...state, badgeCount: payload };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no way we can tell what's going on without seeing the code, my suggestion is to try to reproduce the problem on `snacks.expo.io`

Comment: Maybe you are changing/re-assigning the property, which you are selecting with useSelectors, after every render and the change is causing the component to re-render. Unfortunately, I can't help you properly, without seeing any code snippets.

Comment: I am using logger so I would see those changes as they happen but no properties are changing.

Comment: list your component and reducers, so we can take a look at the code. it's hard to guess what could be doing it without seeing at least the reducer.

Comment: as far as component goes. there is nothing special happening. I grab state from redux like this { someState } = useSelector(state=>state.myState).  and for the reducer it looks like this:  ( I just posted it on the OP )

Comment: Make sure you test it on a production build as hooks are called twice on dev builds anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, the thing is: the useSelector compare the new value with the old one with a strict `===`. You can either call one useSelector per field or implement the `shallowEqual` from `react-redux`:

```
const someState = useSelector(state=>state.myState.someState, shallowEqual)
```

Here the documentation:
https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates