# Function runs two to three times

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, function

I have a function in my react app that capitalized the first letter of a word or string that is fetched from an API:

```
  // Capitalize the first letter of the word/phrase
  const capitalize = (string) => {
    if (string) {
      return string
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
        .join(" ");
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };
```

**Note: `string` is the text that is being fetched from the API. I call the function like so:**

```
capitalize(userInfo.address)
```

It works as expected but upon logging the results to the console, I realized that it is being run two to three times.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-bose-2qr01j?file=/src/App.js

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Where do you call ``capitalize`` function?

Comment: @EtsukoSusui Between a couple of <p> tags to render the UI.

Comment: Could you share full your code on codepen please.

Comment: Reacts `render()` function is called for every state change. If capitalize is called from somewhere within render, it will be called multiple times.

Comment: @EtsukoSusui https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-bose-2qr01j?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this url is empty project

Comment: @EtsukoSusui It is fixed now.

Comment: I think there is problem with ``useselector``
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64178607/useselector-causes-multiple-re-renders

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by [React Strict Mode](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/strict-mode.html). Check your *index.js*. By default React wraps your `<App/>` component with `<React.StrictMode>` which intentionally invokes the `render` method of your inner components two times.

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Just remove it to run functions only once.

```
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function is correct, but perhaps, when it is executed after a call to an external data source, an asynchronous call is being made (and possibly more than one), so the `capitalize` function is executed more than once .

Try to make the function run regardless of where you are calling from.

It could also be that you are executing the function from a code block that is executed more than once, because the function seems to be correct and does not have anything iterative.

Comment: The call to the API is done with Redux Thunk and I can see that it is being called once to get that data. The component that the `capitalize` function is being called from, is part of another parent component that gets rendered at first and then its children populate the UI. (Component Tree = App => Dashboard => Personal Info)